# How do I get the url to a path in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using `<%=link_to "Add fund",addFund_item_path(:id=>item.id),:class=>"addfund btn btn-primary"%>"` to generate a link  to a path in rails.

I want to get only the url (the href) of the path so I can use it in a form. How do i do that?

Comment: damn. missing the obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `addFund_item_path(:id=>item.id)`.

Answer (score 0):

So you just want the actual href?  I would do this:

```
<%= content_tag "a", addFund_item_url %>
```

It won't be a 'link' per se - it will be clickable, but won't go anywhere - but it will show the full href path